# jqGrid Filter rule

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

everyone,

Recently, I use jqGrid's Filter function. I have 'where' clause as following:

**TakeVendor = 'SOME' *AND* Act_ToDoFlag = 'SOME' *AND* VHNO LIKE '%SOME%' *AND* ((A_FLAG = 'true' AND B_FLAG = 'false') *OR* (A_FLAG = 'false' AND B_FLAG = 'true'))**

I don't know how to write jqgrid's filter,

code I write now:

```
            var myfilter = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [] };                

            myfilter.rules.push({ field: "TakeVendor", op: "eq", data: searchVender });                                
            myfilter.rules.push({ field: "Act_ToDoFlag", op: "eq", data: searchFiler });                
            myfilter.rules.push({ field: "VHNO", op: "cn", data: searchVHNO });
```

please help me, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is relatively easy and is described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options) of documentation. You can convert the filter

```sql
TakeVendor = 'SOME'
AND Act_ToDoFlag = 'SOME'
AND VHNO LIKE '%SOME%'
AND (
    (A_FLAG = 'true' AND B_FLAG = 'false')
    OR (A_FLAG = 'false' AND B_FLAG = 'true')
)
```

to the following jqGrid filter

```js
var myfilter = {
        groupOp: "AND",
        rules: [
            {field: "TakeVendor", op: "eq", data: "SOME"},
            {field: "VHNO",       op: "cn", data: "SOME"}
        ],
        groups: [
             {
                 groupOp: "OR",
                 rules: [],
                 groups: [
                     {
                         groupOp: "AND",
                         rules: [
                             {field: "A_FLAG", op: "eq", data: "true"},
                             {field: "B_FLAG", op: "eq", data: "false"}
                         ],
                         groups: []
                     },
                     {
                         groupOp: "AND",
                         rules: [
                             {field: "A_FLAG", op: "eq", data: "false"},
                             {field: "B_FLAG", op: "eq", data: "true"}
                         ],
                         groups: []
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ]
    };
```

One should just take in consideration that `groupOp: "AND"` will be applied for both `rules` and `groups`. After that the above structure of `myfilter` object should be clear.

Comment: Thanks your help very much